# dragon board SPI clock issue

Tags: kernel, clock, spi

I am working on dragon board and I need to connect the SPI device with SPI_QUP modules of dragon board. QUP module is connected on GSBI1 of msm8960.I am successfully running SPI and got appropriate waveform on the scope. I observed that it will send data at a clock rate 10M as default, when I try to reduce its clock rate I am unable to reduce it below 5M.If I reduce it to below 5M it will start sending data at a default rate (10M). My spy device operates at a very slow rate compare to this (about the 3M Max clock speed). Is there any way to reduce it below 5M?

Thanks.

Comment: Issue resolved, But I can use only clock value defined in clock file.

Comment: Please post the specific resolution to your issue, for the benefit of others who may encounter the same problem.